# Insert the capital letters with in curly braces {} in a text file in specific lines

Tags: perl, unix, scripting, awk, latex

I am using a.bib file which have large number of entries. Unfortunately, the capital letters in the title are however not inside curly braces. Can we write a simplified script to put them in curly braces. The example of file is

```
@article{foo2002,
author={Foo, A.},
title = {Eating EGGS Daily},
publisher = {ACM},
year={2010}
}

@article{bar2002,
author={Bar, B.},
title = {Going to School},
publisher = {IEEE},
year={1987}
}

@article{alice2012,
author={Alice, C.},
title = {{A} {G}erman in {UK}},
publisher = {ACM},
year={2012}
}
```

I want to change the title (only title not other lines) such that the capital letters are inside curly braces, for example titles in first two cases should be

```
title = {{E}ating {EGGS} {D}aily},

title = {{G}oing to {S}chool},
```

However, if they are already in curly braces I don't want to change other lines. So, the third case should be as it is

```
title = {{A} {G}erman in {UK}},
```

I have a file from collaborator with 3200 lines. The output should be

```
@article{foo2002,
author={Foo, A.},
title = {{E}ating {EGGS} {D}aily},
publisher = {ACM},
year={2010}
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{bar2002,
author={Bar, B.},
title = {{G}oing to {S}chool},
publisher = {IEEE},
year={1987}
}

@article{alice2012,
author={Alice, C.},
title = {{A} {G}erman in {UK}},
publisher = {ACM},
year={2012}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while (<>)
{
    s/([A-Z]+)/{$1}/g if (/title = {.*},/);
    print;
}
```

Or if you're a fan of Perl one-liners:

```
perl -e 'while (<>) { s/([A-Z]+)/{$1}/g if (/title = {.*},/); print; }' < data
```

---

**Edit**:  If you have some lines that are already properly braced (and no lines that are a mixture that need to be corrected), the following script will avoid re-bracing an already braced line:

```
while (<>)
{
    s/([A-Z]+)/{$1}/g if (/title = {[^{}]*},/);
    print;
}
```

---

**Edit 2**:  If you have some lines that have a mixture of properly-braced and not-properly-braced capital letters, the simplest method I can think of is to take two passes through a regular expression:  one to add braces, and one to remove double-braces:

```
while (<>)
{
    s/([A-Z]+)/{$1}/g if (/title = {.*},/);
    s/{{([A-Z]+)}}/{$1}/g if (/title = {.*},/);
    print;
}
```

Comment: Works exactly the way I wanted. But Just realized I have to escape the ones that have the curly braces. So, how can I escape the curly braces. For eg. if title has

    title = {{G}oing to {S}chool},

I want to leave it as it is and do not want to add extra spaces.

Comment: @lovedynasty : So if I understand correctly, some lines already have the necessary curly braces, so you don't want to accidentally double them up?

Comment: Is there ever a case with a mixture that needs to be fixed, like this?  `{This {O}ne is {M}essed Up}`?

Comment: Most of the cases are not like that but it will be useful to treat this case and put braces around U in {U}p too

Comment: @lovedynasty: I don't know an easy way off-hand (as my advanced perl regex fu is weak) other than to do the replacement and then strip away the double-braced.  I'll add a second edit above.

Answer (score 1):

this one-liner should do:

```
awk -F'\\s*=' '$1=="title"{gsub(/[A-Z]+/,"{&}",$2)}7' file
```

Comment: I tried your script on the provided data and it did not work.  It output the data unmodified.

Comment: I checked, BTW, and `awk` on my system is just an alias for `gawk`.  `awk --version` returns the same version string as `gawk --version`.

Comment: That one gave me some weird results, like `title  {{E}a{ting} {EGGS} {D}a{ily}},`  (notice it ate the `=` sign too?) and `title  {{Going} {to} {School}},`.

Answer (score 1):

by sed

sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

```
 sed '/title =/ s/\([A-Z]\+\)/{\1}/g;s/{{\([A-Z]\+\)}}/{\1}/g'  a.bib
```

If not get right output, try this:

```
 sed '/title =/ s/\([A-Z][A-Z]*\)/{\1}/g;s/{{\([A-Z][A-Z]*\)}}/{\1}/g' a.bib
```

Comment: It does not put E of Eating and D of Daily and G of going for sed 4.2.1